# POST data with python

Tags: python, post

I wanted to POST some data to a site using python.

Suppose the data are the following:

```
payload = {
    'key': 'value',
    'user-point-form-1': random_data #the data I want to post
}
```

and the html where I want to post that is:

```
<div class="alert-user-point-a"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="user-point-form-1" value="XXXXXXXXX">
```

I tried doing `response = s.post(url, data=payload)` but it seem didnt work. How should I change the request so I post the data where the "XXXXXX" is?

Comment: What is the form target and are you sure it is a `POST`?

Comment: And what is `s` variable?

Comment: It doesnt have, and yep am sure its a POST, the `s` is `s = requests.Session()` a few lines above

Comment: How do you read `random_data` and what do you see when you're printing it to stdout ?

Comment: Suppose `random_data="just a text"` and am not printing anything in the stdout, just checking if the changes applied to the value on the online site

Answer (score 1):

So you want to write to a html in a website? This is not techinacally post but I get what you mean...  this is more like webscraping. One tool that does that is selenium, but be aware it is quite a mountain to climb. Selenium solves the problem of automating web navigation, using the usual webbrowsers. You have to choose a language (Java, python, etc. etc.) and get a library for the language that links to selenium. Python is `pip install selenium`. Then you need to install a driver that talks specifically to a browser brand (Firefox, Chrome, Safari). See details of installation [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html). Next you use the library. It allows you to open windows programatically (silently if you configure that) and send keys to fields, click buttons, etc.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Am confused, isnt that pretty much what I've been doing? I was thinking perhaps the payload "key", or 'user-point-form-1' where wrong

Comment: The concept of `posting data to html` is wrong. You can't do that in a technical sense. What you can do is to build a robot that opens your webbrowser for you and write what you want in the field you want programatically. Is that what you mean by posting data to an html?

Comment: Oh I didnt know. I guess if thats the only solution then yes thats what I want, although I would prefer, if it could run it in the background silently without opening chromedriver but thats the result I want, yes.